# HTML5 audio playlist opens up new tab when clicked in Meteor web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I'm working on a web app in meteor and I'm trying to use the HTML5, CSS and Javascript audio playlist in my app:

```js
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
```

```css
#playlist,audio{background:#666;width:400px;padding:20px;}
.active a{color:#5DB0E6;text-decoration:none;}
li a{color:#eeeedd;background:#333;padding:5px;display:block;}
li a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">Ravel Bolero</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">Moonlight Sonata - Beethoven</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">Canon in D Pachabel</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip">patrikbkarl chamber symph</a></li>

    </ul>
```

When I try to click on the li to play a song it opens the file up in a new tab with the audio in white and a black background.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this as I've been stuck on this issue for almost three days now.

Thanks,
Dillon Davis

Comment: What frontend engine doi you use? Blaze/React/Angular/Vue/etc ?

Comment: I think Meteor @Jankapunkt

Comment: Then you can't just invoke the function right away. You need to understand the Template engine first: blazejs.org is the documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

.I've just loaded jQuery in the snippet you've provided, and that worked fine. No other changes were required.

Check below snippet:

```js
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
    
    audio[ 0 ].addEventListener( 'canplay', function( e ) {
    
      this.play();
    
    }, false );

}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

}
```

```css
#playlist,audio{background:#666;width:400px;padding:20px;}
.active a{color:#5DB0E6;text-decoration:none;}
li a{color:#eeeedd;background:#333;padding:5px;display:block;}
li a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">Ravel Bolero</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">Moonlight Sonata - Beethoven</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">Canon in D Pachabel</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip">patrikbkarl chamber symph</a></li>

    </ul>
```

**Update:** I've added `play()` method after player loaded audio

---

**Update 2:** I've moved `.play()` to `canplay` event.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate this answer but sadly this didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: what do you need to do? this just worked for me, it changes audios from `#playlist` @DillonJ.Davis

Comment: I ran the code you gave me and it didn't work. I don't know. @mrReiha

Comment: @DillonJ.Davis well, then give me some more details. What browser are you using? Which version? What OS? and what exactly do you expect from this code? And what do you mean it doesn't work? For example, do you expect it to play the selected song? Or just replace the src?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 but it's also not working in Safari. macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6. I'm expecting that when I click on the song in the li tag it plays the song without opening a new tab @mrReiha

Comment: @DillonJ.Davis Do you see any thrown error when you click **Run snippet** just like your snippet? Because your own throws an error. And I just checked with chrome as well, worked fine. I think you expect it to play the song, while it just replaces the src. I'm going to update snippet to play the song after changing `src`.

Comment: I'll try it if you edit the code again. It might be me running on Meteor @mrReiha

Comment: @DillonJ.Davis This is my last try. Definitely should work. Please recheck it.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate the help but this didn't work either. Thanks though.